# How to broadcast matrix/vector dot product in tensorflow.js

Tags: javascript, tensorflow, broadcast, tensorflow.js

How can I broadcast the multiplication of a matrix A with multiple vectors in Tensorflow with Javascript ?
Let's define A:

```
A = tf.tensor2d([1, 0, 0, 2], [2, 2])
A.print()
Tensor
    [[1, 0],
     [0, 2]]
```

Let's define the b vectors as column vector (matrix):

```
b = Array.apply({}, new Array(10)).map(_ => tf.tensor2d([[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)], [Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)]]));
b[0].print()
Tensor
    [[90 ],
     [122]]
```

Trying `.matMul`:

```
A.matMul(b)
tfjs@latest:2 Uncaught Error: Error in matMul: inputs must have the same rank of at least 2, got ranks 2 and 1.
```

or `.dot`:

```
A.dot(b)
tfjs@latest:2 Uncaught Error: Error in dot: inner dimensions of inputs must match, but got 2 and 10
```

Also tried with b as regular 1d tensor:

```
b = Array.apply({}, new Array(10)).map(_ => tf.tensor1d([Math.floor(Math.random() * 100), Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)]));
```

Results are the same. Moreover, looking at the doc it seems that those operations are not broadcastable. I don't see why they can't be as `numpy` is able to broadcast them.

I saw some answer to the same question for python suggesting the use of `einsum`. But it seems to be available only for python, not javascript.

Comment: You should make `b` a 2D tensor with shape `(2, 10)` and then `A.matMul(b)`, the resulting `(2, 10)` tensor will have each vector product in the columns.

Comment: I guess I could do that but apart from the fact that I find it inelegant, it also means allocating and copying data from a big list of tensors to a big tensor. Something I'd like to avoid.

Comment: Thinking about your answer, I found an easy way to do that: tf.stack. I need to see the performance impact but at least it's easy and elegant.

Comment: Actually, `tf.stack` is very slow. And even crash when trying to stack too many tensors (100000). Back to square one.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a broadcasting issue. `b` is a normal JavaScript array. In this case it is an array of tensor. 
To use b in `dot` or `matMul` operation, b needs to be a tensor. That is not the case here.
For a `matMul` operation, given two tensors `x (shape [p,q])`, `y (shape [r, s])`, q should be equal to r. This is the very definition of a matrix multiplication, ie there is no brodcasting for matMul either in tensorflow.js or in tensorflow.py. The dot operation is very similar. The only difference is that one operand can be a matrix and the second a vector.

Consider the following: for the sake of simplicity, what is in brackets is a tensor of that shape.

```
[4, 5].matMul([5, 6]) = [4, 5].dot([5, 4]) => [4, 6]
```

```
[4, 5].matMul([4, 5]) => error
```

because of 4 and 5 (ie why to do the square of a matrix is sometimes defines as the product between the matrix and its transpose. For given a matrix A,  A*A could not always be computed unless A is a square matrix)

```
[5].dot([5, 4]) => [4]
[5, 4].dot([4]) => [5, 1]
```

```
[5].dot([4, 5]) => error
[5, 4].dot([5]) => error
```

To compute the product of b and a, you will need to iterate over b and do the matMul operation.

```js
a = tf.tensor2d([1, 0, 0, 2], [2, 2])

// there is much simpler way to create an array of 10 tensors without apply function
const b = Array.from({length:10}, _ => tf.tensor2d([[Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)], [Math.floor(Math.random() * 100)]]))
// Matmul operation
const prod = b.map(t => a.matMul(t))
prod.forEach(t => t.print())
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Load TensorFlow.js -->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@tensorflow/tfjs@0.12.0"> </script>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. However I believe you illustrate my question without answering it. I believe the principle of broadcasting is to do exactly what you do with the `map` there, but do it in a much faster way (numpy does the loop in native code). Sure I could loop (and I did) but instead of looping in a very slow interpreted language, I'd like tensorflow (like numpy) to loop "internally" in an optimized way (numpy distribute the loop over multiple cores for example depending on your math backend).

Comment: @LukeSkywalker, can you please edit your question with the numpy code?